# MessageConverter not being called

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a custom MessageConverter registered in spring with the following configuration:

```
<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="com.eventwiz.web.util.ServiceResponseHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <util:list id="beanList">
        <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
      </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, it's not being called as I confirmed that with a breakpoint in my code.  ServiceResponseHttpMessageConverter subclasses MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and overrides writeInternal() method.  I've even tried overriding MessageConverter.supports() just to see if that was being called and it wasn't.  Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Question: Is Spring MVC being configured any other way: say using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` if yes, then the converters registered directly though annotationDrivenHandlerAdapter are probably not taking effect

Comment: Yes Biju you are correct annotation-driven was the problem.  I had to upgrade my schemas to 3.1 and used the <mvc:message-converters> child tag to configure them.  It's now working as expected.  If you want to add this as the answer I can award you the points.

Comment: Great, I have now added an answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as was found based on an answer from the author was the  `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag which registers its own handlerAdapter, so if another handlerAdapter is added to the Spring MVC configuration file with converters added to this adapter, the custom adapters will not take effect. The fix is to either register the httpMessageConverters through `<mvc:message-converters...` tag under `<mvc:annotation-driven` or removing `<mvc:annotation-driven` and having the custom handleradapter with the httpmessageconverter registered under it.